# What happens to View Controllers when iPhone is rotated?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios-simulator

Working on my app, I'm running across a problem that is causing the app to shut down without any error messages. I can't find anything wrong with the code, and it only happens when a certain chain of events occur.

Here's what happens: Under a navigation controller, if you go at least two views in, then rotate the iPhone to landscape, then attempt to go back, the app crashes immediately. I've added some debug NSLog lines to help me understand the problem, revealing that the view controllers are not working as I previously thought they did.

When I rotate the phone (simulator), do all the views in the stack become notified of the change? And can anyone shed some light as to why this might be causing a crash? Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen when going 1 view in?  Or does it crash when going at least two?

Comment: It only happens if you go two in, rotate the view, then attempt to return to the first one. Also, if you rotate it back to portrait before returning to the first one it still crashes.

Comment: Interesting.  In that case I would substitute the deepest view with a bare bones view to see if the problem is isolated to one of those views.  If it doesn't crash, then you know its specific to that view.  I'd be interested to know your findings.

Comment: It sounds like the first view is crashing in the viewDidAppear of the first view's controller.

Comment: @Jeremy Good thoughts. I just added a few `NSLog' statements to the `viewDidAppear` method, and it looks like it is never called since the statements were never logged. I will try substituting another view, then.